# Spring mass system, vertically hanging mass

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

A object of mass 2kg is hanging vertically on a spring. The spring is extended 0.1m from its equilibrium position. How would you find the spring constant?

$my'' +ky=mg$

$y''+ \frac{k}{2} = 9.8$

The homogeneous solution: $e^{it \sqrt{\frac{k}{2}} }$ and $e^{-it \sqrt{\frac{k}{2}} }$

$y_h =c_1 cos\sqrt{\frac{k}{2}}t +c_2 sin\sqrt{\frac{k}{2}}t $

The particular solution:$y_p=\frac{19.6}{k}$

So $y=\frac{19.6}{k} + c_1 cos\sqrt{\frac{k}{2}}t +c_2 sin\sqrt{\frac{k}{2}}t$

Comment: Perhaps you had better clarify whether the weight itself pulls the spring $0.1$ m out of its unweighted equilibrium position, or if you pull the system $0.1$ m further out of its *weighted* equilibrium position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Am I missing something?  Isn't the spring constant obtained simply by balancing the forces at equilibrium?

$$
F_{\text{grav}} = F_{\text{spring}}
$$

$$
mg = kx
$$

and therefore

\begin{align}
k & = \frac{mg}{x} \\
  & = \frac{(2 \text{ kg})(9.8 \text{ m}/\text{s}^2)}{0.1 \text{ m}} \\
  & = 196 \text{ N}/\text{m}
\end{align}

Comment: Wow im bad. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Notice,

in the equilibrium condition of the spring mass system, $$\text{spring force in vertically upward direction}=\text{weight of object in vertically downward 
direction}$$ 
$$kx=mg$$$$\implies k=\frac{mg}{x}$$
setting $m=2\ kg$, $g=9.8\ m^2/s$ & $x=0.1\ m$, spring constant $k$
$$k=\frac{2\times 9.8}{0.1}=\color{red}{196\ N/m}$$

Answer (score 0):

Spring Constant's dimension is N/m

The equation is simply equating $kx = mg$  It is not a second order eqation.

$k = \frac{2\times 9.8}{0.1} = 196$N/m by Hooke's law